# How to stack 3 elements under each other when phone display-

Tags: css, responsive, display

I am trying to style - newsletter - input - submit so that when you see the web in your phone the three elements show up one under the other- and all the boxes in the same size and align.
Does anyone have an easy solution for this? Ill appreciate your help very much. Regards and thanks!  http://vtwg.eu/michael/index.html
V

```
<div id="contact-area">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">NEWSLETTER</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</div>




input {
padding: 5px;
width: 120px;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
border: 3px solid black;
background: white;
}


.submit-button {
float: center;
font-size: 1em;
}

label {
font-family: arial;
text-align: center;
width: 120px;
padding: 5.5px;
background:#57007F;
border: 3px solid black;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: http://vtwg.eu/michael/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change design elements for mobie view, you should use *media query*. In the snippet media query set to max-width of viewport equal 480px. You can change this value as you wish. When you narrow browser window 
down to less than 480px, you'll see the diference.

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: white;
}
.submit-button {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 5.5px;
  background:#57007F;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  input, .submit-button, label {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-area">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">NEWSLETTER</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Banzay! thanks so much, totally what i needed to do :D

Answer (score 0):

Write styles in media query with respect to the resolution.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contact-area">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">NEWSLETTER</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    input {
padding: 5px;
width: 120px;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
border: 3px solid black;
background: white;
}


.submit-button {
float: center;
font-size: 1em;
}

label {
font-family: arial;
text-align: center;
width: 120px;
padding: 5.5px;
background:#57007F;
border: 3px solid black;
margin-left: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    label,
    #Name,
    .submit-button
    {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 5px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    }
```